# Compiling 2.4.20 kernel in (CentOS 6.5) 2.6.32 kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, linux-kernel, centos

My target system running on top of 2.4.20 Linux kernel. Till now my host environment also has been running on the same kernel. Now i am planning to change my Host Environment to Cent OS 6.5 which is running on 2.6.32 kernel. What is the best way to successfully compile kernel 2.4.20 on it? How to customize my host environment to compile my old kernel?

Comment: You can compile 2.4.20 on 2.6.32. I think there won't be any dependencies on compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to compile 2.4.20 on CentOS 6.5.
The 2.4.20 kernel need `gcc-2.95.3` and `binutils-2.9.1.0.25` which are very obsolete. Besides, `gcc-2.95.3` may need an older version of `glibc` which is impossible to be installed on CentOS 6.5. If you really need to compile kernel-2.4.20, you can download RedHat 7.3 (released in 2001) and use this system to compile the old kernel.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am getting so many errors while compiling the kernel. Is there any way to install or create environment in CentOS 6.5 with the older versions of gcc, binutils, glibc?

Comment: @Eshwar I have tried this way two years ago, but failed. Then I downloaded RedHat 7.3 and finally compiled successfully.